# Как получить значение src в class_ = 'small-gallery-image'

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Необходимо получить значение в src (url картинки). Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://memepedia.ru/trending/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
array = soup.find_all(class_ = 'entry-title')
hrefs = [el.select('a')[0]['href'] for el in array]
#print(hrefs)

r1 = requests.get(hrefs[0], headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text)
arr1 = soup1.find_all(class_ = 'small-gallery-image')
print(arr1)
```

Вывод:

```
[<figure class="small-gallery-image">
<a class="bb-js-gallery-link" data-class="post-gallery-lightbox" data-id="#post-gallery-184644" href="#post-gallery-184644_0"><img alt="Крот" class="attachment-boombox_image360x270 size-boombox_image360x270" height="270" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/photo_2019-06-11_00-31-07-360x270.jpg" width="360"/></a>
</figure>, <figure class="small-gallery-image">]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустил ваш код, получил `arr1` содержащий 11 элементов `<figure>`. Для получения значения атрибута `src` из `<img>` сделал так:

```
imgs = [el.img.get('src') for el in arr1]
```

Результат:

```
['https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/photo_2019-06-11_00-31-07-360x270.jpg',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/neh3gdkkdgx-rf7-rcn24uw9rvgzt9fdk66lupmnsluzoihaxnbjrqabnb7nawu_qmkag4bsekfspizimmaw757nt_yi2egqun3xvhg8l88-1-360x270.jpg',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_4-2-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/photo_2019-06-12_03-28-37-360x270.jpg',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/photo_2019-06-12_15-15-47-360x270.jpg',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_8-4-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_6-3-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_5-3-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_2-3-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/screenshot_1-3-360x270.png',
 'https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/photo_2019-06-07_18-39-04-360x270.jpg']
```